# call tracert and ping from sql and put the result in sql table

Tags: sql-server-2005, traceroute

I need to create a stored procedure which will get destination IP and then call tracert or ping and then write the result into a sql table so then I can show user the result in a web page . 
is it possible to do this ? if yes would you please tell me how because I have searched a lot and didn't find a proper solution .
and if not what do you suggest ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify as needed -

```
declare @results table(result varchar(500))

insert into @results
exec sp_executesql N'xp_cmdshell ''ping www.yahoo.com'''

select * from @results
```

Similarly for tracert

```
declare @results table(result varchar(500))

insert into @results
exec sp_executesql N'xp_cmdshell ''tracert www.yahoo.com'''

select * from @results
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution I write this part for those who want to run query like me and will see the error that xp_cmdshell is not accessible : 
USE master GO 
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 GO 
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE GO 
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 GO 
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE GO 
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0 GO